# Animated graphic in front of frame title?

Tags: beamer, graphics, backgrounds, animations

I am using the beamertemplate and I have one frame:

```
\frame{
\frametitle{Title text}
\begin{textblock*}{50mm}[1,1](15.9cm,9cm)
\includegraphics[width=1.9cm]{thumbnail.png}
\end{textblock*}
\vspace{-0.5cm}
\hspace{1cm}
\animategraphics[scale=0.4,autoplay]{8}{movie}{000}{200}

}
```

The problem is, that the animatedgraphic has white space at the top, which is covering my title text. So how can I tell LaTex, that the title text is "more important" and that the title is in front of the animatedgraphic? So that the animatedgraphic is in the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Animated graphics produced with the `animate` package are rendered within PDF annotations (interactive regions) which live, by design of AdobeReader, in a separate layer *in front* of the page content.

Thus, you will have to remove the excess white space of your graphics files before embedding if you want to prevent it from obscuring the page content.

Alternatively, you can use the `bb=...`, `viewport=...` or `trim=...` options of the `\animategraphics` command. See the `animate` package doc. And don't forget to remove the negative `\vspace`.

Comment: Damn - I just wanted to use a animation in the **background canvas** of a `beamer` presentations which didn't work (was always in the foreground). Now I know why.

Comment: @manuel Try option `method=ocg`. However, it is slow.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and it works - and yes, it is (too) slow (for my use case :)). Still - the package is amazing.

Comment: @manuel That is because the whole PDF page content is re-rendered with every animation frame when using the `ocg` method, not just the annotation appearance.